# Compile time error in dereferencing the map pointer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};

struct node* newNode (int data)
{
    struct node *temp = new struct node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}


void printVerticalUtil(struct node *root, map<int, vector<struct node*> > *m, int index){
    if(root == NULL)
        return;

    *m[index].push_back(root); // compiler error 
}


int main(){
    struct node *root, *res;
    root = newNode(1);
    map<int, vector<struct node*> > m;
    printVerticalUtil(root, &m, 0)
}
```

I am passing map address in `printVerticalUtil()` function using pointer, I am getting compiler error at  `*m[index].push_back(root);`  I can't understand the error (no matching function  to call)

I know if i pass by reference , it would work but i want to know what is wrong with passing by pointer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression

```
*m[index].push_back(root)
```

is the same as

```
*(m[index].push_back(root))
```

In other words, you try to dereference what the `push_back` function returns, and since it doesn't returns anything that can be referenced (it doesn't return anything at all) you get a compiler error.

What you want is

```
(*m)[index].push_back(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about operator precedence. You would have to deference the pointer first, to get at the map

```
(*m)[index].push_back(root);
```